# In fish true == 0, but false != 1?

Tags: bash, boolean, fish

In fish, `true` seems to equal `0`:

```
❯ if true == 0; echo "YES"; else; echo "NO"; end
YES
```

But `false` seems to not equal `1`:

```
❯ if false == 1; echo "YES"; else; echo "NO"; end
NO
```

In bash both of them are not equivalent to their numeric value:

```
$ if [ true == 0 ]; then echo "YES"; else echo "NO"; fi
NO
$ if [ false == 1 ]; then echo "YES"; else echo "NO"; fi
NO
```

It seems strange that fish would be consider one truth value equal to its numeric counterpart but not the other.

Maybe there is an explanation for that?

Comment: `In bash both of them are not equivalent to their numeric value:`?? In Bash a __string__ true and a __string__ false is just that - a string.

Comment: You are passing arguments `==` and `0`/`1` to the `true`/`false` commands... it's not the shell reading those (I mean, technically it is, because those are builtins, but I mean, not the part that would handle actual shell syntax). So you don't have a comparison here other than what `if` does, which is "check if the result of the following command has a zero exit code". That's because in your Fish example, you didn't use the `[` command which you did use in Bash.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, `true` and `false` are strings, but they're also the names of (builtin) commands. The commands can be used directly (not in `[...]`) as conditions: `ok=true ; if $ok ; then echo OK ; else echo 'Huh?' ; fi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `true` ignores arguments and exits with zero exit status meaning success.

```
if true you can put literally anything here; echo "YES"; else; echo "NO"; end
```

The command `false` ignores arguments and exits with non-zero exit status which means failure.

```
if false you can put literally anything here too; echo "YES"; else; echo "NO"; end
```

The equivalent Bash code is:

```
if true anything here; then echo "YES"; else echo "NO"; fi
if false anything here too; then echo "YES"; else echo "NO"; fi
```

The command `[ true == 0 ]` executes the command `[` and compares the **string** `true` to the **string** `0`. Because `true` and `0` are different strings, the comparison is (logically) false, so `[` command exits with non-zero exit status. Similarly with `false == 0`. Note that `==` is an extension to `[` - it's `[ true = 0 ]` in standard `[`.

You can compare that in Fish the `[` command also "both of them are not equivalent to their numeric value" too:

```
if [ true == 0 ]; echo "YES"; else; echo "NO"; end
if [ false == 1 ]; echo "YES"; else; echo "NO"; end
```

Comment: Once upon a time (version 2.7) the `fish` builtins `true` and `false` would raise an error if you gave them any arguments. Now (version 3.5) it just silently ignores them. (And in neither version is any mention of arguments documented.) I guess it's trying to be more POSIX compatible?

Comment: "I guess it's trying to be more POSIX compatible" -- more like it's changing to meet the expectations of users.